# Derivations of $\frak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $\frak{g} = \frak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

> What is the Lie algebra of derivations $\text{Der}(\frak{g})$?

Recall a Lie algebra derivation is a linear map $f: \frak{g} \to \frak{g}$ such that $f([x,y]) = [f(x),y] + [x,f(y)]$.

I know that $\frak{sl}_n := h$ is a semi-simple Lie sub-algebra of $\frak{g}$ and we can write $\frak{g} =  h \oplus d$ for $\frak{d}$ the Lie sub-algebra of diagonal matrices.

Moreover, for any semi-simple Lie algebra the derivations are all inner (that is, of the form $ad(x))$.

So if $f$ is a derivation on $\frak{g}$ it is easy to see that $f$ preserves $\frak{h}$: because $\frak{h} = [\frak{g}, \frak{g}]$. If it preserved $\frak{d}$ we could write: on $\frak{d}$ a derivation is just a linear map. So is the conclusion is that any derivation is of the form $f = f_1 + ad(h)$ where $f_1$ is any linear map on $\frak{d}$  and $h \in \frak{h}$?

However I don't know if it's true that $f$ preserves the diagonal matrices.

Any assistance?

Comment: Assume $y$ is a diagonal matrix then since diagonal matrices commutes with every other elements that makes first 2 terms in the derivation equation zero.The argument then follows.

Comment: Just to clarify, we're talking about *scalar* diagonal matrices, not just any diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the center $Z(L)$ of $L=\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb C)\cong \mathfrak{sl}_n(\Bbb C)\oplus Z(L)$ is a *characteristic ideal* of $L$, it is preserved by all derivations of $L$.